# Hi I tried to copy this program by watching the video. I got error after using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

Video description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hjNG9GZGnQ&t=204s

GitHub: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

This is the error in localhost:8080

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 22 18:48:10 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
```

Comment: Why don't you just post a comment to the video on youtube or ask on github and come back with a specific issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.